Adjust layout of tikz arrows in table
i have the following question. I want to add arrows to my booktabs table. I have already tried it and got them drawn in, but I still have problems with the layout of the arrows. I have this code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
\toprule
Day $d$ & $a_{ijk}$ & $b_{ij}$ & $v_{ijk}$ & $f_{ijk}$ & $e_{ij}$ & $f_{ijk}$ & $g_{ij}$ \\
\midrule
1 & $(1,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $1$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
2 & $(1\tikzmark{a},0,0)$ & $0$ & $(1\tikzmark{c},0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
3 & $(0,1\tikzmark{b},0)$ & $0$ & $(1\tikzmark{d},0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,1\tikzmark{e},0)$ & $0+1+0=1$ \\[10pt]
4 & $(0,\tikzmark{f}0,0)$ & $1$ & $(0,\tikzmark{g}1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
5 & $(0,0,1)$ & $0$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $0+0+1=1$ \\[10pt]
6 & $(0,0,1)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=.25\baselineskip}]
    \draw [red, ->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:b});
    \draw [red, ->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:c}) -- ({pic cs:d});
    \draw [red, ->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:b}) -- ({pic cs:f});
    \draw [red, ->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:d}) -- ({pic cs:g});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) [bend left] to ({pic cs:e});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}

which produces this output.
I would like the red arrows to always start in the centre below/above the number (with a marginal distance) and then run in the centre of the lower number. Currently they start in the centre of the number. I would like the same for the black arrow, but I would also like it to be curved but not cover a number or be angular. Something like this:


It might be easier to do this with the nicematrix package. This way, each cell would automatically be a node which one could use to draw the arrows.

Crossposted over at reddit. Please do not waste people's time.

You can use tikzmarknode for this. The black arrow is still created mostly manually. If you use nicematrix instead of booktabs you could use the node coordinates of each cell to create that arrow automatically.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={outer sep=2pt}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
\toprule
Day $d$ & $a_{ijk}$ & $b_{ij}$ & $v_{ijk}$ & $f_{ijk}$ & $e_{ij}$ & $f_{ijk}$ & $g_{ij}$ \\
\midrule
1 & $(1,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $1$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
2 & $(\tikzmarknode{a}{1},0,0)$ & $0$ & $\tikzmarknode{c}{1},0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
3 & $(0,\tikzmarknode{b}{1},0)$ & $0$ & $(\tikzmarknode{d}{1},0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,\tikzmarknode{e}{1},0)$ & $0+1+0=1$ \\[10pt]
4 & $(0,\tikzmarknode{f}{0},0)$ & $1$ & $(0,\tikzmarknode{g}{1},0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\[10pt]
5 & $(0,0,1)$ & $0$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $0+0+1=1$ \\[10pt]
6 & $(0,0,1)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $0+0+0=0$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [red, ->] (a)--(b);
    \draw [red, ->] (c)--(d);
    \draw [red, ->] (b)--(f);
    \draw [red, ->] (d)--(g);
    \draw [->] (a)|-++(5.8,.4)--++(0,-.8)-|(e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}

